# How to setup PATH to sh script in gitlab pipeline?

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a bash script `plan.sh` that executes multiple times during the pipeline execution.

```
plan:
  before_script:
   - chmod +x ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan/plan.sh     
  script:    
    - cd ${FOLDER1}
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan/plan.sh
    
    - cd ${FOLDER2}    
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan/plan.sh

    - cd ${FOLDER3}
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan/plan.sh
```

I would like to execute script using just a file name instead of full path. So I am setting the PATH environment variable.

```
plan:
  before_script:
   - export PATH=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan:$PATH
   - chmod +x plan.sh     
  script:    
    - cd ${FOLDER1}
    - plan.sh
    
    - cd ${FOLDER2}    
    - plan.sh

    - cd ${FOLDER3}
    - plan.sh
```

However this throws error

> $ chmod +x plan.sh
> chmod: cannot access 'plan.sh': No such file or directory

Comment: chmod still needs the exact path to the file, be it relative or absolute. Just a filename won't work, even if it's in your PATH.

Comment: Perhaps you could `export PLANPATH="${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan/plan.sh"` first and then use `${PLANPATH}` for `chmod` (and executing it, don't let the shell find a rouge `plan.sh` via `PATH`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PATH` is used to look up the location of binaries when executing them by their name only.

`PATH` is *not* used to resolve arbitrary file arguments passed to another binary. For `chmod` this means that you still have to provide the full path (relative or absolute) or `cd` to the correct directory first.

Here's another example that does/not work:

```
PATH=/bin
cd /

ls bin/ls       # works
ls /bin/ls      # works
bin/ls bin/ls   # works
bin/ls /bin/ls  # works
/bin/ls /bin/ls # works

/bin/ls ls      # error
bin/ls ls       # error
ls ls           # error
```